# How to share localStorage data between Chrome Browser (or Chrome Custom Tabs - CCT) and WebViews?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, webview, chrome-custom-tabs

I have an Android app with a WebView which loads multiple URLs with links. Some of these URLs are opened in a Chrome Browser (or Chrome Custom Tabs) and these loaded pages write to localStorage using `window.localStorage.putItem("someKey", "someValue")`.

When I try to access those values from my WebView by doing a `window.localStorage.getItem("someKey")` the returned result is null.

Conversely, if I write a value to localStore in my WebView and then try to read it from Browser I see the null value again.

My WebView has javaScript and domStorage enabled:

```
class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    public Context mContext;

    public HelloWebViewClient(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        launchCCT(url);
        return true;
    }


    private void launchCCT(String url) {
        CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
        CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = builder.build();

        Bundle headers = new Bundle();
        customTabsIntent.intent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_HEADERS, headers);

        customTabsIntent.launchUrl(MainActivity.this, Uri.parse(url));
    }
}


WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);

myWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient(this));
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
myWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);

myWebView.loadUrl(<url goes here>);
```

Also the Target API in manifest.xml is 31 running on Android 11.

My WebView displays the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function chromeCustomTabOpen()
            var Window;
            Window = window.open(
                "https://myserver/setLocalStorageValue");

        }

        function readFromLocalStorage() {
            alert("Some value is: " + window.localStorage.getItem("someKey"))
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button onclick="chromeCustomTabOpen()">
        Open Custom Tab
    </button>

    <button onclick="readFromLocalStorage()">
        Read from local storage
    </button>
</body>
</html>
```

First I click the `Open Custom Tab` button which loads the following HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body onpageshow="onpageshowMethod()">
        <h1>Set Local Storage Value</h1>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function onpageshowMethod(event) {
                window.localStorage.setItem("someKey", "someValue");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then I close the CCT and when I am back to the WebView I click on `Read from local storage` button which results in `null` value shown in alert.

**How do I force Android to share localStorage values across Browser (or CCT) and WebViews?**

Comment: Kan you tell full path of those storages? In general apps on Android 11+ devices have no access to other apps files.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have not explicitly configured the storage paths. Is there a default path that Chrome (CCT) uses? Also the `setDatabasePath()` API is deprecated as per the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings#setDatabasePath(java.lang.String)  . Can you please let me know if there is some configuration that I can use to force the apps to share localStorage? Alternatively, do you know if the behavior with Cookies would be the same?

Comment: `When I try to access those values from my WebView by doing a window.localStorage.getItem("someKey")` Sorry, i do not see that in your code and have no idea of what 'window' would be. Please post all relevant code. Or do you mean that it is just the javascript in a page displayed by a WebView?

Comment: `I have not explicitly configured the storage paths` Does not matter. I only asked to find out the full paths and tell here.

Comment: Updated the code snippets to include WebView HTML and the HTML that sets the localStorage in CCTs.

Comment: > I only asked to find out the full paths and tell here.  -- I am not very well versed with storage paths and how Android sets them by default. Can you please let me know how I can find the current storage path?